# Get XAMPP to divert to my site automatically

Tags: xampp

When I enter my domain name into the web browser, eg. www.mysite.com, xampp automatically diverts to www.mysite.com/xampp

How can I change it to go directly to my site folder eg. www.mysite.com/mysite

Thanks and Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be with Apache configuration.

Please check your httpd.conf file and check also if any virtual hosts (v-hosts) are defined.

More details on the httpd.conf file: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/configuring.html